# Restore Content Database to a different farm (Prod -> Beta -> Dev Servers)

Tags: database, restore, backup, sql-server

My end goal is to have some code that automatically takes the Content Database backup from Production and automatically nightly restores it on Beta.  Can I just do backup and restore sql commands? Or do I have to do some type of detach/attach process instead of restore?

I wrote a console app that does the following:

**1. LockDownSharepoint**
 - I turn off the timer service and set all site collections to Writeblocked and Readblocked ( is it neccessary to set ReadBlocked to true? or just writeblock)

**2. Restore Content Database**
 - I set the Database to singleuser mode
 - I run the restore command

string.Format("**USE master RESTORE DATABASE [{0}] FROM  DISK = N'{1}' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10**", BackupDBName, FullFilePath);

- I set the Database to multiuser mode

**3.Unlock SharePoint**
 - Turn on the timer service and set readblocked and writeblocked to false.

The code works in my development environment when I try to restore a database backup that I took from the same content database.  **restoring **DEV1_ContentDB over DEV1_ContentDB works****!

However, as soon as I run it in a different environment, but try to restore the content database from my dev environment, things go work.  **restoring DEV1_ContentDB over DEV2_ContentDB does NOT WORK**.

It properly connects to the Database and runs the restore sql command with no errors.  But when it is done the site collection is shot...and I can't connect to it to turn back read and write access..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was that I was trying to restore a database backup file to a database of a different type.  First I tried renaming the target database to the same name as the source database, but that didn't work.

The Solution:

1. Lock Down Sharepoint on SOURCE
2. Physically copy the SOURCE_ContentDB.mdf
3. Unlock SharePoint on Source
4. Attach SOURCE_ContentDB.mdf to DESTINATION
5. Go through Central Admin and remove the previous content database and add SOURCE_ContentDB

Those were the initial steps necessary.

Now I can use my code as desired to automatically take backup files from SOURCE and restore them to DESTINATION.